# Can I duplicate a SO question?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076370/most-underused-data-visualization is an awesome question. It's not particularly suited to stack overflow though. I think it is definitely suited to CV, although it could probably be asked more precisely. I asked the moderators on SO to move it here, and the response was "declined - No, I think it would be too subjective there too. You can try re-asking it, but I won't migrate it."

Can I re-ask this question, or would it be worth re-trying to get it moved over, or should I not bother, because this question (or one like it) likely to be closed on CV as well?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't recommend reposting this question on Cross Validated. First, cross-posting is not the way to go. Second, it is overly broad and does not focus on specific issues related to data analysis. `big-list`-like questions are [not a good fit for this type of Q&A site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/150510), which is probably why the question was closed on SO despite the huge traffic there. Another reason not to migrate is that it was posted long ago and it is has attracted a large number of upvotes on SO.

I am not saying that responses were bad, or that the question itself might not be interesting (provided it was more firmly delineated: e.g., "what are good alternatives to scatterplot when one wants to study covariation between skewed numerical variables", or "beside scatterplot, what are good way to highlight a trend between two series of hourly measurement", or "under which conditions does it help to also display marginal densities in a scatterplot", etc.--where discussions on pros and cons, and on-line references, are expected). As it stands, this question just call for a list of nice visual displays which are unlikely to help future users with a specific problem in mind.

Comment: I find it somewhat strange that a question more than a year old with many answers and upvotes could be closed because it "isn't a good fit to this type of Q&A site". I'd say the *users* of SO had clearly demonstrated that it was a great question and a perfectly reasonable fit to the format. I can't fathom how a moderator thought their individual wisdom was far greater than the collective wisdom of the people who actually *generate the content*. Empiricism replaced deduction several centuries ago. Let's see how it works out here.

Comment: @Bogdanovist This issue has been debated _to death_ on meta.SO, so I won't rehash any more of it here, except to say this: trust me, this is a contentious issue with significant numbers of folks who feel passionately about it _on both sides_. big-list question may be good or bad, but don't be fooled by up/down vote patterns into thinking that there isn't a _significant_ number of folks who think they should all be closed.